Getting error invalid number format model when multiplying a varchar2 define column with -1 and need result in NUMBER(19,2) datatype in Oracle
This query in Oracle throwing an error

ORA-01481: invalid number format model

SELECT TO_NUMBER(CODE * -1, 19,2)
FROM CUSTOMER;

where the CODE column defined as varchar2 in the table CUSTOMER.


In any non-trivial system, it's pretty likely that there are some non-numeric characters in a varchar2 column that would cause your query to fail.  2) 19 is not a valid format model and 2 is not a valid NLS parameter.  My guess is that you want -1 * to_number(code) or that you want to wrap that in a cast if you want to ensure the result is a number(19,2) rather than just a number.


What do 19,2 represent? These values are invalid for to_number function.
Without that, presuming that code - although declared as a varchar2 column - doesn't contain invalid values (i.e. something else than digits), then apply to_number only to code:
SQL> create table customer (code varchar2(3), name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into customer (code, name) values ('100', 'Scott');

1 row created.

SQL> select to_number(code) * -1 result, name
  2  from customer;

    RESULT NAME
---------- --------------------
      -100 Scott

SQL>

If you want to format result so that it contains decimal point, then e.g.
SQL> select to_char(to_number(code) * -1, '999G990D00') result, name
  2  from customer;

RESULT      NAME
----------- --------------------
    -100,00 Scott

SQL>

Or, did you mean to use cast?
SQL> select cast(to_number(code) * -1 as number(19, 2)) result from customer;

    RESULT
----------
      -100

SQL>

